# Ajax delete method in spring boot

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

After looking on different questions on forums talking about the same problem, I still don't know how to resolve my **Request method 'DELETE' not supported**

An Ajax method call is fired when a user in the **client-side** press a button, this method retrieves the **sportId** wrapped in an Ajax call and send to spring controller to Delete method.

**Ajax method:**

```
function removeRow(link) { 
    var sportId = link.getAttribute("data-sport-id");

    $.ajax({
        type : "DELETE",
        url : "/sports-actions",
        data: {id : sportId},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function (result) {       
               console.log(result);                
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
   })   

}
```

**Spring controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sports-actions")
public class SportController {  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public Object deleteSport(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

even if I send id in url, I still get the same error

**Ajax code:**

```
 $.ajax({
        type : 'DELETE',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url : "/sports-actions?id="+sportId,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function (result) {       
               console.log(result);                
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
   })
```

Comment: Check your `AJAX` request, you are not passing id in the request url. Instead you are sending in the body. The url could be -> url: `'/sports-actions/' + sportId`.

Comment: I still get the same error, I have done this before.

Comment: Look for the difference between `@PathVariable` and `@RequestParam`. In your edit case scenario, use `@ReqeustParam`.

Comment: oh, I really forget about that, it was a part of the solution. it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending request to incorrect url. You declared path for the controller as `/sports-actions/{id}`, but actually sending it to `/sports-actions` with json body.

Correct code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "DELETE",
    url : "/sports-actions/" + sportId,
    success: function (result) {       
           console.log(result);                
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Please see the difference between `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable`.

If you want to use `@ReqeustParam`:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "DELETE",
    url : "/sports-actions",
    data: {"id" : sportId},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (result) {       
           console.log(result);                
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})   

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sports-actions")
public class SportController {  

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public Object deleteSport(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you want to use `@PathVariable`

```
$.ajax({
    type : "DELETE",
    url : "/sports-actions/" + sportId,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (result) {       
           console.log(result);                
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}) 



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sports-actions")
public class SportController {  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public Object deleteSport(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**PS**: It is always good to follow `Restful` best practices. [see here](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)

Comment: I was focusing on my Ajax call and I completely forget about this important part, great point

Answer (score 0):

**Without jQuery $**

AJAX-based requests can be rather cumbersome to formulate unless you add helper libraries like jQuery. The new Fetch API promises an easy-to-use Promises-based alternative here.

Here is an example:

**SPRING BOOT (JAVA)**

```java
@DeleteMapping("/items/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteItem(@PathVariable Long id) {
    // delete the item with the specified id
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
function deleteItem(id) {
    fetch(`/items/` + id, {
      method: 'DELETE'
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFetch(12);">DELETE</button>
```

---

**BONUS: Spring Security**

If you are using Spring Security you need to a CSRF credentials to the header:

**HTML**

```html
<!--/* Security */-->
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}">
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
let token = document.querySelector("meta[name='_csrf']").content;

fetch(`/my-data/business/delete/` + id, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
});
```