# How to fix Spring boot controller getting null data from AJAX DELETE request?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have tried using @QueryParam, @PathVariable and @RequestParam but my controller is not getting data request from AJAX call. I have the same approach with my other methods. Only the DELETE request is not working and I am getting null value. I have referred to this [Ajax delete method in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018581/ajax-delete-method-in-spring-boot) but it is not working for me.

```
//AJAX DELETE
var id = {"id":$("#deleteUserIdInput").val()};

$("#deleteUserModal").modal("hide");

$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:3000/delete-user",
    datatype : "json",
    method : "DELETE",
    data : id,
    contentType : "application/json",
    error:function(data){
        console.log(data.entity);
    }
}).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data.entity)
    }
);

//Controller
//http://localhost:3000/delete-user
@RequestMapping(value="/delete-user", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public Integer deleteUser(@QueryParam("id") Integer id){
    return id;
}
```

I am testing data before passing to request and it is not null. I expect the data passed to the request to be returned, for example 1, but I am getting undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are sending the id as the body of your request. That means you'd need to have your `deleteUser` method receive the body as a parameter.

What I suggest you do is DELETE from a specific URL i.e. http://localhost:3000/users/{id}

The corresponding method declaration becomes:

```
@DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Integer deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
    return id;
}
```

And your JS will need modifying (I think - I am no good at JS) to something like (again - I am not a JS guy, sorry if this is awful!):

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:3000/users/" + $("#deleteUserIdInput").val(),
    datatype : "json",
    method : "DELETE",
    contentType : "application/json",
    error:function(data){
        console.log(data.entity);
    }
}).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data.entity)
    }
);
```

Comment: It worked. I have tried @PathVariable first before other annotations and it does not work but now its working I don't know why XD. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Renzchler When you use `@QueryParam("id")`, you need to pass the key and value as a URL parameter, instead of as the body, by appending `?key=value` to the URL. So, your original ajax request should have looked like this: `"http://localhost:3000/delete-users?id=" + $("#deleteUserIdInput").val()`

Answer (score 0):

I think , your can't get value ,may be  is the  servre cors。
can you config cors ?

first request can get value for delete request , actually the delete requst is cors Virtual requst , ajax comfirm your server is ok ,can ajax go ahead send agin.

you can change post requset ,and in server change  post to  receive  you requset.

Comment: Yes bro, I have set my CORS config properly and the only method that is not working is the DELETE but its working now XD. Thank you for your help!

Comment: i see you paste javascript,the server get value is undefined ,may be your script send  value is undefined ,not server problem。

Comment: you can change  script post requst ,and  server requst receive mothod body @parthPathVariable  and ,script data body json{“you PathVariable value”:"value"}.